# psutil without C extensions

Tags: python, psutil

I'm considering using *psutil* for CPU and Volumes monitoring. However, for my project it would be ideal if I could somehow get rid of the C extensions *psutil* uses:

- I want my project to be as self-contained as possible with no need for compilation on client side.

Is this possible? Or is there and earlier pure-python version of *psutil* I can use?

Comment: you can use `cx_freeze` to pack the project with psutil

Comment: is there any tutorial on cx_freeze usage you can recommend?

Answer (score 0):

Not possible out of the box. The only thing you can do if you're using Linux is to copy & paste the Python parts you need reading from /proc (they are a lot) in your own project: https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil/blob/master/psutil/_pslinux.py

Answer (score -1):

What you need is to **distribute** your project (that is to turn your `.py` scripts into executable programs for normal users, e.g. `.exe` and `.msi` in Windows).

There are many tools to help you, and I will take `cx_freeze` for example.

First, open CMD and `cd` into your project:

```
C:\Users\xiao>cd Desktop
C:\Users\xiao\Desktop>cd foo-project
```

Then, run `cxfreeze-quickstart` and follow the instruction:

```
C:\Users\xiao\Desktop\foo-project>cxfreeze-quickstart
Project name: foo
Version [1.0]:
Description:
Python file to make executable from: bar.py
Executable file name [bar]:
(C)onsole application, (G)UI application, or (S)ervice [C]: C
Save setup script to [setup.py]:

Setup script written to setup.py; run it as:
    python setup.py build
Run this now [n]? y
```

Finally, you can see the executable file in `build` directory.

You can download cx_freeze on [SourceForge](http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/); for advanced information, [read the docs](http://cx-freeze.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).